# Best way to compress xml text column using SQL?

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, xml, compression

Using Microsoft SQL Server 2019.
I have two columns, one text representing some xml, another varbinary(max) representing already compressed xml, that I need to compress.
Please assume I cannot change the source data, but conversions can be made as necessary in the code.

I'd like to compress the text column, and initially it works fine, but if I try to save it into a temp table to be used further along in the process I get weird characters like ‹ or tŠÌK'À3û€Í‚;jw.  Again, the first temp table I make stores it just fine, I can select the initial table and it displays compressed correctly. But if I need to pull it into a secondary temp table or variable from there it turns into a mess.

I've tried converting into several different formats, converting later in the process, and bringing in the source data for the column at the very last stage, but my end goal is to populate a variable that will be converted into JSON, and it always ends up weird there as well. i just need the compressed version of the columns do display properly when viewing the json variable I've made.
Any suggestions on how to tackle this?

Comment: You can't change the source data but you're messing around with compression? Just store XML data in the `xml` column type. SQL Server already converts the source XML data to [InfoSet format](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-infoset/) for storage which, depending on the data, can be around a 30% storage saving... and is completely transparent to T-SQL code.

Comment: `COMPRESS` function can actually reach impressive storage saving on XML data. Getting down to 30 % of original size is possible. I'm talking about 100 GB reduction in 200 GB table.

Answer (score 0):

**Collation issue?**

This smells of collation issue. `tempdb` is actually its own database with its own default collation and other settings.

1. In one database with default `CollationA` you call `COMPRESS(NvarcharData)` and that produces some `VARBINARY`.
2. In other database (`tempdb`) with default `CollationB` you call `CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), DECOMPRESS(CompressedData))`. Now, what happens under the hood is:

   - `CompressedData` gets decompressed into `VARBINARY` representing NvarcharData in `CollationA`
   - that `VARBINARY` is converted to `NVARCHAR` *assuming* the binary data represents `NVARCHAR` data in `CollationB`, **which is not true**!

Try to be more explicit (collation, data type) with conversions between XML, VARBINARY and (N)VARCHAR.

**Double compression?**

I have also noticed "*representing already compressed xml, that I need to compress*". If you are *doublecompressing*, maybe you forgot to *doubledecompress*?

**Example?**

You are sadly missing an example, but I have produced minimal example of converting between XML and compressed data that works for me.

```sql
BEGIN TRANSACTION
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.XmlData_Base (
  PrimaryKey INTEGER NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1),
  XmlCompressed VARBINARY(MAX) NULL
);
GO

CREATE OR ALTER VIEW dbo.XmlData
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
  SELECT
    BASE.PrimaryKey,
    CONVERT(XML, DECOMPRESS(BASE.XmlCompressed)) AS XmlData
  FROM
    dbo.XmlData_Base AS BASE;
GO

CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER dbo.TR_XmlData_instead_I
  ON dbo.XmlData
  INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO dbo.XmlData_Base
    (XmlCompressed)
  SELECT
    COMPRESS(CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), I.XmlData))
  FROM
    Inserted AS I;
END;
GO

CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER dbo.TR_XmlData_instead_U
  ON dbo.XmlData
  INSTEAD OF UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
  UPDATE BASE
  SET
    BASE.XmlCompressed = COMPRESS(CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), I.XmlData))
  FROM
    dbo.XmlData_Base AS BASE
    JOIN Inserted AS I ON I.PrimaryKey = BASE.PrimaryKey;
END;
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.XmlData
  (XmlData)
VALUES
  (CONVERT(XML, N'<this><I>I call upon thee!</I></this>'));

SELECT
  *
FROM
  dbo.XmlData;

SELECT
  PrimaryKey,
  XmlCompressed,
  CONVERT(XML, DECOMPRESS(XmlCompressed))
FROM
  dbo.XmlData_Base;

UPDATE dbo.XmlData
SET
  XmlData = CONVERT(XML, N'<that><I>I call upon thee!</I></that>');

SELECT
  *
FROM
  dbo.XmlData;

SELECT
  PrimaryKey,
  XmlCompressed,
  CONVERT(XML, DECOMPRESS(XmlCompressed))
FROM
  dbo.XmlData_Base;
GO

ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
```